# False "value computed is not used" warning

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc-warning, gcc4.7

I'm maintaining some ugly legacy code with the following function and I am getting

```
warning: value computed is not used
```

for the lines marked by comments below:

```
void ReadKeyValuePipe(char* buffer, char* key, char* value) {
    char* pos;
    char key_str[1024];
    char* val = value;
    sprintf(key_str,"%s:",key);
    if((pos = strstr(buffer,key))) {
        pos += strlen(key_str);
        while (*pos && *pos != '|') {
            *val = *pos;
            *val++; // this is actually used
            *pos++; // so is this
        }
        *val = 0;
    }
}
```

When I remove those lines, the code breaks. Which makes sense because they appear to be incremented markers.

How do I get the compiler to recognize that these calculations are actually used?

Comment: They're not used - see the linked duplicate.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the latent buffer overflow from calling `sprintf`. At the very least, throw in `assert(strlen(key) + 2 <= sizeof(key_str));`

Comment: @Casey This entire function seems like the wrong way to do this to me but I have to pick my battles.

Comment: WTF? `key_str` is only used is an inefficient way to calculate `1 + strlen(key)`? Should that be `strstr(buffer, key_str)` instead? This function truly is horrible.

Comment: Seriously. If I were going to rewrite this function, I would just convert any `char*` to `string` and do it with [string splitting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/130427).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dereferencing `val` and `pos` and then incrementing them, but you never use the result of the dereferencing. You can just replace those lines with:

```
*val = *pos;
++val;
++pos;
```

Or, probably what the code originally was before somebody "fixed" it:

```
*val++ = *pos++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-Wno-unused-value` compiler option if you are sure that your code is correct.
Which is not, since you obviously don't know what `*val++;` does.

```
*val++; 
*pos++;
```

is the same as:

```
 val++;
 pos++;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that this ugly legacy code and my new additions sometimes do have actual unused values and I rely on the warnings to recognize and eliminate this. (I wasn't the person who down voted you).

Comment: You can apply `-Wno-unused-value` to only the few lines of code with the problem using the `pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` approach